# What are the possible values for 'reason' parameter when dismissing a Bootstrap UI Modal window?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I'm working on an AngulaJS project and using the Bootstrap UI Modal window component.

To close a Modal window, most examples use the following line of code:

```
$uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
```

I noticed that the `dismiss` function receives a parameter called `reason`:

> dismiss(reason) (Type: function) - Can be used to dismiss a modal,
>   passing a reason.

I tried to look for any information, but haven't come across with something that explains the possible values for the `reason` and the effects they could have.

Does anyone know what possible values can this parameter receive and how it affects the modal window behavior? Are some values best for some scenarios than others?

Comment: Reason is entirely up to you.  Can be any string you like.  Since `$uibModalInstance` returns a promise, you can use the reason later on down the flow.

Comment: So it's just a string value I can come up with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no "possible values" for `reason`: the optional parameter value is passed into the *closing event* that is broadcast as part of the `dismiss()` call.

That is, you can have listeners attached that watch your modal instance. When your `dismiss()` is called, those listeners will be triggered with the `reason` value supplied as an event parameter.

From the `angular-ui` source:

```
 function broadcastClosing(modalWindow, resultOrReason, closing) {
    return !modalWindow.value.modalScope.$broadcast('modal.closing', resultOrReason, closing).defaultPrevented;
  }
```

See source: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js#L514-L516

Comment: So I can safely assume the `result`/`reason` can be either a string or an object? can it be a function? Are there any specifics I should avoid to do when using the `result`/`reason` parameter?

Comment: I don't see any reason that a function cannot be supplied but recognize that this is likely an anti-pattern. The event model tells its subscribers that _something_ has happened but does not normally prescribe _what needs to be done_ within the event itself.

Answer (score 2):

The reason can take any value and doesn't effect the behavior of the modal window at all.  The purpose of the reason is to allow the code that opened the modal to react accordingly.

For instance if you were interested in learning whether the modal closed because a user hit cancel or a server call errored out you could have

```
$uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel') //user hit cancel button
```

or

```
$uibModalInstance.dismiss('serverError') //error in server call within modal
```

Comment: So the only purpose is purely as information feedback to whoever opened the modal?

Comment: Correct, it is only relevant to the application code.  The ui-bootstrap library does nothing with it